# problems with Google API quickstart.py code

Tags: python

I am starting to learn how to use to google api for Google Calendar and I am getting this error. I set up my OAuth 2.0 client_secret.json file as a web application and even tried adding the local host as the redirect Url. However, when i try to run the sample code to test out the api: https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/master/calendar/quickstart/quickstart.py and sign in I get the error linked below. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[link to picture of error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYGtp.png)

Comment: Please provide code

Comment: The code is just the github code linked above with my secret json file instead of credentials.json

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.